# Rust include mod

Tags: rust

I have such a hierarchy:
src/main.rs

```
mod animals;
mod race
fn main() {
  let s = animals::Animal(12.0, 1.8, 24, animals::race::white);
  println!("Hello, world!");
}
```

src/animals/animal.rs

```
mod race;
pub mod animal {
  pub struct Animal {
  height: f64,
  weight: f64,
  age: u32,
  raceT: race
  }
}
```

src/animals/race.rs

```
pub mod race{
  pub enum Race {
      whit,
      black,
      yellow
  }
}
```

and a have this arror:

```
--> src\main.rs:1:5
  |
1 | mod animals;
  |     ^^^^^^^
  |
 = help: name the file either animals.rs or animals\mod.rs inside the  directory "src"

 error: aborting due to previous error
```

How to add modules properly so that there are no errors

Comment: "name the file either animals.rs or animals\mod.rs" -- in other words move your animals.rs to your top level src-directory or rename it mod.rs inside the animals/-directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rename `animals.rs` to `mod.rs`. [Here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch07-05-separating-modules-into-different-files.html) you can find more information on splitting modules across files.